# Optimize tensorflow computation

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I used tensorflow for a while, and I've seen it reaches good time performance by training a big neural network on a GPU. Now, for some motivation, I have a code similar to the following:

```
 neural_networks = [first_nn]
 for i in range(N):
     new_nn, new_parameters = GetNewNN()
     previous_model = sum(neural_networks)
     optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).\
            (tf.reduce_mean(
               tf.square(target - previous_model - new_nn)),
            var_list=new_parameters )
     for t in range(T):
            session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={target:y})
     neural_networks.append(new_nn)
```

Every time I add a neural network, the computation becomes really slower, even thought that every new_nn is a single layer neural networks with 10 neurons! On my computer is way faster to run and train a neural network of 1000 neurons then running few neural networks with ten neurons (and training only one of them per time).

I tried to optimize the code in several different way, but without gaining any performance benefits. How can write a more efficient code?

Comment: Um -- what are you trying to do with `previous_model = sum(neural_networks)`? It looks like you're adding together all the previous networks? That could slow it considerably (read: quadratically). As in, with $N=10$, it would be expected to be about as slow as 1 instance of 1000 neurons. I think a larger sample of code might also be good.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to sum up all the models. Why do you say quadratically? I was expected linearly, and even less, thinking that actually the summation could be parallelized.